# Не отправляется файл на сервер(Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня компонент input для файла и кнопка отправить

```html
<FileUpload mode="basic" name="file" :customUpload="true" @select="previewFile" />
<button @click="uploadTask">отправить</button>
```

Также переменная для записи файла`const files = ref(null)`
И функции для отправки запроса и записи файла в переменную files

```
async function uploadTask() {
        const formData = new FormData()
        console.log(files.value[0])
        formData.append('file', files.value[0])
        const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
            },
            body: formData
        })
        const result = await response.json()
        console.log(result)
    }

    function previewFile(e) {
        files.value = e.files
        console.log(files.value[0])
    }
```

Проблема в том, что в console.log'ах видно что файл есть но при отправке, в теле запроса пусто.

Comment: Если вопрос все еще актуален создайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, на [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) или любом другом аналогичном сервисе.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так.

```js
const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: formData
        })
```